# Use of relative path results in FileNotFoundException

Tags: bash, shell, war

I am trying to write a shell script to create a war file of the specified folder. Getting target location as a command line argument did not cause any problem. But getting target location(as relative path) during run time throws below mentioned error.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~/app/sss.war (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:110)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:192)
    at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1231)
```

I have also included the script

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter target location : " loc
jar -cf $loc/sss.war *
```

But using absolute path works fine. I just want to why using relative path didn't work.

Comment: Try: `mkdir ~/app`

Comment: that folder exists already